Create FAT-formatted disk image that can fit 1G file
I'm struggling to create a FAT-formatted a disk image that can store a file of known size. In this case, a 1 GiB file.
For example:
# Create a file that's 1 GiB in size.
dd if=/dev/zero iflag=count_bytes of=./large-file bs=1M count=1G
# Measure file size in KiB.
LARGE_FILE_SIZE_KIB="$(du --summarize --block-size=1024 large-file | cut --fields 1)"
# Create a FAT-formatted disk image.
mkfs.vfat -vv -C ./disk.img "${LARGE_FILE_SIZE_KIB}"
# Mount disk image using a loopback device.
mount -o loop ./disk.img /mnt
# Copy the large file to the disk image.
cp --archive ./large-file /mnt

The script fails with the following output:
++ dd if=/dev/zero iflag=count_bytes of=./large-file bs=1M count=1G
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 39.6962 s, 27.0 MB/s
+++ du --summarize --block-size=1024 large-file
+++ cut --fields 1
++ LARGE_FILE_SIZE_KIB=1048580
++ mkfs.vfat -vv -C ./disk.img 1048580
mkfs.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
Auto-selecting FAT32 for large filesystem
Boot jump code is eb 58
Using 32 reserved sectors
Trying with 8 sectors/cluster:
Trying FAT32: #clu=261627, fatlen=2048, maxclu=262144, limit=65525/268435446
Using sector 6 as backup boot sector (0 = none)
./disk.img has 64 heads and 63 sectors per track,
hidden sectors 0x0000;
logical sector size is 512,
using 0xf8 media descriptor, with 2097144 sectors;
drive number 0x80;
filesystem has 2 32-bit FATs and 8 sectors per cluster.
FAT size is 2048 sectors, and provides 261627 clusters.
There are 32 reserved sectors.
Volume ID is f0de10c3, no volume label.
++ mount -o loop ./disk.img /mnt
++ cp --archive ./large-file /mnt
cp: error writing '/mnt/large-file': No space left on device

How do I create a FAT-formatted disk image that's large enough store a file of known size?
Resources:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd
https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.vfat
https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount
https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#Size_limits

EDIT 1
My assumption was that mkfs.vfat -C ./disk.img N would create an image that has N KiBs of usable space, but I guess that's not the case.
EDIT 2
It seems like a dead end to try to calculate exactly how big the disk image needs to be to store a file of known size because of the complexities around FAT sector/cluster size limits.
As suggested in the answers, I've settled for adding 20% extra space to the disk image to allow for FAT overhead.

It would seem to me you're trying to fit a file on a file system that doesn't have enough space – by design! You're basically saying "For a file that takes N kB, make a disk image exactly N kB in size". Where exactly is FAT going to store the file metadata, directory tables and volume descriptor?
With FAT32, the standard duplicate superblock, and the usual directory table + long file name table, plus 32 reserved sectors somewhere on the disk, from the top of my head, you'll want a couple of MB extra space, around 4 MB, I guess, for file systems this huge¹.
You're also using mkfs.vfat with defaults, which was a sensible configuration for PCs made in the 80s and early 1990s, which means there's smaller sectors, and hence more sectors to keep track of, and hence more consumption by the FAT to store a single file. Maximize the sector size; on a file system with more than 1GB of available space (so, disk image significantly larger than 1GB!), 16 kB should work (minimum "FAT32-legal" cluster count is 65525, divide 1GB by that assuming 4kB sectors,so -S 4096, and maximize the cluster size to 16 sectors, so -s 16).
Also note: with 1 GB you're already dangerously close to the maximum file size of FAT32 – 2 GB. So, if this is intended to be some storage for e.g. backup or file system images, you might quickly find yourself in a situation where FAT32 doesn't suffice. It's a very old filesystem.
Addendum: How to figure how much larger to make the image than the content
As sketched above, FAT is a bit annoying, because it has arbitrary (and surprisingly low!) limits on the number of sectors, which makes it a bit hard to predict how much overhead you'll incur.
However, the good thing is that Linux supports sparse files, meaning that you can make an "empty" image that doesn't "cost" any storage space. That image can be larger than you need it to be!
You then fill it with the data you need, and shrink it back to only the size you want.
Generally, your script from your question does a few questionable things, and there's more sensible ways to achieve the same; I'll comment in code on what my commands are equivalent to. The idea is simply: make a much larger-than-necessary, but "free" in terms of storage, image file first, fill it with the file or the files you need, check how much free space you have left. Subtract that space from your image size, make a new image, be done.
# File(s) we want to store
files=( *.data ) # whatever you want to store.
imgfile="fat32.img"

# First, figure out how much size we'll need
# use `stat` to get the size in bytes instead of parsing `du`'s output
# Replace the new line after each file size with a "+" and add the initial overhead.
initial_overhead=$(( 5 * 2**20 )) # 5 MiB
# Then use your shell's arithmetic evaluation $(( … )) to execute that sum
totalsize=$(( $(stat -c '%s' -- "${files[@]}" | tr '\n' '+') initial_overhead ))

# give an extra 20% (no floating point math in bash…), then round to 1 kiB blocks
img_size=$(( ( totalsize * 120 / 100 + 1023 ) / 1024 * 1024 ))

# Create a file of that size
fallocate -l ${img_size} -- "${img_file}"
mkfs.vfat -vv -- "${img_file}"

# set up loopback device as regular user, and extract loopback
# device name from result
loopback=$(udisksctl loop-setup - "${img_file}" | sed 's/.* \([^ ]*\)\.$/\1/')

# mount loopback device as regular user, and get mount path
mounted=$(udisksctl mount -b "${loopback}" | sed 's/^.* \([^ ]*\)$/\1/')

# make sure we're good so far
[[ -d "${mounted}" ]] || (echo "couldn't get mount"; exit -1)

# copy over files…
cp -- "${files[@]}" "${mounted}"
# … and unmount our file system image
udisksctl unmount -b "${loopback}"
udisksctl loop-delete -b "${loopback}"

# use df to directly get the amount of free space in kilobyte blocks
free_space=$(df --direct --block-size=1K --output=avail -- "${img_file}" | tail -n1)

# We no longer need our temporary image
rm -- "${img_file}"

# subtract 2 kB just to be on the safe side when making new image
new_img_size=$(( free_space - 2 ))
# Make a new image, copy over files
fallocate -l ${new_img_size} -- "${img_file}"
mkfs.vfat -vv -- "${img_file}"
loopback=$(udisksctl loop-setup - "${img_file}" | sed 's/.* \([^ ]*\)\.$/\1/')
mounted=$(udisksctl mount -b "${loopback}" | sed 's/^.* \([^ ]*\)$/\1/')
[[ -d "${mounted}" ]] || (echo "final copy: couldn't get mount"; exit -1)
cp -- "${files[@]}" "${mounted}"
udisksctl unmount -b "${loopback}"
udisksctl loop-delete -b "${loopback}"

# Done!


¹:  when FAT32 was introduced, a 1 GB hard drive was still not a small one, and file system structures hail down from FAT12, in 1981, and designed for 360 kB sized floppy disks; the amount of blocks you could possibly have to keep account for that 1 GB hard drive would have was simply not to materialize for another 15 years or so. In essence, smart phones formatting SD cards to FAT32 carry around a time capsule for a file system invented in ~ 1997, which in itself is a relatively slight modification of a file system invented in 1980; so, yay, solving modern storage problems with compromise solutions from 44 years ago.

Thanks Marcus, I appreciate your response.
"For a file that takes N kB, make a disk image exactly N kB in size" – Yeah my assumption was that mkfs.vfat -C N would create an image that has N KiBs of usable space, but I guess not.
"you'll want a couple of MB extra space, around 4 MB, I guess, for file systems this huge" – Yes, this make sense. Do you know how to do an exact calculation of extra space needed?

no, but I'll add a bit to my question on how I'd approach the problem of figuring out!

@jdeanwallace done! But now I'd  really like to know what exactly you need "precisely trimmed" FAT images for!

Thanks @MarcusMüller, I've accepted your answer. My intended use-case is to make a FAT-formatted disk image from a directory of files (using built-in linux commands).

I wonder what you need that image for; that you want that image, that's what we already know. So, what are you planning to do with that image?

I modified your code and added some additional comments.
It works as it stands:
# Create a file that's 1 GiB in size.
dd if=/dev/zero iflag=count_bytes of=./large-file bs=1M count=1G

# Measure file size in KiB. BUT TWICE THE SIZE!
# Double parentheses are needed for arithmetic
LARGE_FILE_SIZE_KIB=$(($(du --summarize --block-size=1024 large-file | cut --fields 1) * 2))

# Create a FAT-formatted disk image.
sudo mkfs.vfat -vv -C ./disk.img "${LARGE_FILE_SIZE_KIB}"

# Create mount directory
sudo mkdir /mnt/test

# Mount disk image using a loopback device.
sudo mount -o loop -t vfat ./disk.img /mnt/test

# Copy the large file to the disk image.
# BUT do not use --archive option
sudo cp ./large-file /mnt/test

EDIT:
Disclaimer.
I didn't investigate why minimum size of the virtual disk should be double the size of the file being copied.
But I suspect it has to do with block size which was either too low or too high to accommodate 1GB file.

but why twice the size?

@MarcusMüller To make large enough virtual disk because file was exactly the size of vdisk which is why it didn't work, trial and error made me, I really have no clue why smaller numbers didn't work though.

That would be great to say in the answer! I think going "twice as large as the file" is a bit conflicting with the needs of the asker

@MarcusMüller You're right, I've made an edit for lack of additional context and explanation.

long time ago I would use a 110% size to dupplicate a filesystem for backup/copying purpose, 1) those were not FAT but AIX's jfs 2) It was a fulll filesystem, not a single file.  -- It can't reproduce as I don't have 2+ Gb of disk (despite being in "storage" dep) 2) I don't have mkfs.vfat :(

Thanks @metablaster, I appreciate the attempt, but as Marcus has pointed out I'm more interested in a universal solution where I'm able to calculate the exact space needed to store a 1 GiB file.
